# Consumer thread does not get notified

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am trying to implement a Producer/Consumer test program to better understand the low levels of threading.

The idea is that there's a shared resource, the producer fills in the resource with some data, and notifies the consumer that the data is available, while the consumer waits to be notified.

Unfortunately, the consumer thread never wakes up, and so it waits indeterminate.

This is the source code:

```
public class ProducerConsumerTest {

private final Object lock = new Object();

private final static int N = 10;

/**
 * The producer thread
 */
private class ProducerThread extends Thread {
    private final Resource resource;

    ProducerThread(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    System.out.println("Put the resource " + i + " in the container");
                    resource.put(Integer.toString(i));

                    System.out.println("Notify the consumer");
                    lock.notifyAll();

                    System.out.println("Wait until it is consumed");
                    lock.wait();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * The consumer thread
 */
private class ConsumerThread extends Thread {
    private final Resource resource;

    ConsumerThread(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    System.out.println("Waiting for the resource " + i + " to arrive");
                    lock.wait();

                    String s = (String) resource.get();
                    System.out.println(s == null ? "<null>" : s + " ok!");

                    System.out.println("Notify the producer we are done.");
                    lock.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * The main method
 */
public static void main(String argv[]) throws InterruptedException {

    Resource<String> resource = new Resource<>();

    ProducerThread producer = new ProducerConsumerTest().new ProducerThread(resource);
    ConsumerThread consumer = new ProducerConsumerTest().new ConsumerThread(resource);

    producer.start();
    consumer.start();
}
```

}

and the resource class:

```
public class Resource<T> {

    private T resource;

    public synchronized void put(T resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    public synchronized T get() {
        return resource;
    }
}
```

and this is the output:

```
Put the resource 0 in the container
Notify the consumer
Wait until it is consumed
Waiting for the resource 0 to arrive
```

Before arriving to this version of the program, I had some issues with `IllegalMonitorStateException` being thrown when calling `wait() or notify()`. 
After some research I found out that this was happening because the current thread didn't own the object monitor `wait()` was calling on. 
So, having

```
synchronized(lock){
    lock.notify();
    lock.wait();
}
```

would fix the problem with the exception.

And then I was thinking that sharing the lock between the 2 threads would allow to manage the execution. But, as you can see from the output, the consumer thread waits and never is waked up.

Would appreciate any help.

---

EDIT:

```
// Producer 
public void run() {
    try {
        synchronized (lock) {
            System.out.println("Put the resource " + 1 + " in the container");
            resource.put(Integer.toString(1));
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
    }
}



// Consumer
public void run() {
    try {
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (resource.get() == null) {
                lock.wait();
            }
            String s = (String) resource.get();
            System.out.println(s == null ? "<null>" : "Resource " + s + " arrived!");
            resource.clear();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `notify` do if no other thread has called `wait` (yet)?

Comment: You can use `notifyAll` so letting other threads to continue.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Honestly I don't know what does notify() do if no other thread has called wait(). I assume it does nothing in this case. )

Comment: I used notifyAll(), still the output is the same.

Comment: That's right. So if your producer thread gets into its `synchronized` block first and calls `notify` (and then block on `wait`), it won't `notify` anything and the consumer thread will then `wait` indefinitely.

Comment: Hm..., for the sake of testing I started the consumer first, then after 1 sec. the producer. The output was only slightly modified, the consumer first saying it is waiting, then the producer saying it is putting the first element, and then it waits again indefinitely.

Comment: At least, am I using the `lock` correctly?

Comment: In the linked post, pay very special attention to _Usually, wait and notify are used to have one thread wait until some condition is true, and then to have another thread signal that the condition may have become true._ Modify your code to follow that.

Comment: First, find out and learn correct producer-consumer implementation. Reinventing the wheel is a thankless job. Your implementation contains too many errors to list them all.

Comment: I edited the post and added the modifications where one thread waits for a condition and another notifies it. Unfortunately, this works only for 1  cycle. I removed the `for` cycle which was iterating until `N`. What I would like is to have a cycle, and with every iteration the resource to be put into, then wait until is consumed, and then begin another iteration and so on until `N`. But, as @AlexeiKaigorodov suggested, this might not be the correct approach for a Producer/Consumer.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov, reinventing the wheel may be a very bad idea when you're writing production code---every new line of code you write is a liability, not an asset---but when you're trying to learn how wheels work, or when you want to learn how things like the wheel got invented...